# How to loop through several XML input files and copy correlated attribute values to a row in an HTML output table

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to loop through several input files creating a table in an HTML output file where each row corresponds to a review, but I'm not able to get the corresponding @date value and copy it into the corresponding cell of the table. Any help would be very much appreciated.

XML input files

File 1

```
<review rid="id_001" date="2018-03-20">
    <pc pid="pc_001">
        <result>...</result>
    </pc>
    <pc pid="pc_002">
        <result>...</result>
    </pc>
</review>
```

File 2

```
<review rid="id_002" date="2018-05-19">
    <pc pid="pc_001">
        <result>...</result>
    </pc>
    <pc pid="pc_002">
        <result>...</result>
    </pc>
</review>
```

Desired HTML output

```
<!-- @pid value outside the table as header. --> 
<table>    
    <tr>
        <td>Review ID</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Result</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>001</td>
        <td>2018-03-20</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
        <td>002</td>
        <td>2018-05-19</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="files" select="collection('../?select=*.xml')"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<!-- @pid value outside the table as header. --> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Review ID</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Result</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:if test="$files">          
            <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($files/review/@rid)">
                <xsl:variable name="currentRid" select="distinct-values($files/review/@rid)"/>            
                <xsl:variable name="currentPid" select="distinct-values($files/review/pc/@pid)"/> 
                <tr>
                    <td>                  
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($files/review/@date)">                     
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values($files/review[@rid=$currentRid]/pc[@pid=$currentPid]/result)"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>      
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you were trying to iterate over *all* `review` element's `@date` values. Restricting the `for-each` expression to the `review` element matching the `current()` `rid` like you did in the next `xsl:value-of` expression gives you the desired output. So change

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($files/review/@date)">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($files/review[@rid=current()]/@date)">
```

---

I cannot estimate if the `xsl:for-each` is even necessary - that depends on the bigger picture - but maybe the following expression suffices

```
<xsl:value-of select="$files/review[@rid=current()]/@date"/>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Both expressions work. In principle, there is no bigger picture: the input files are as basic as examplified, as well as the tables in the HTML output. The only additional code between <xsl:template match="/"> and <table> refer to HTML layout.